# Using protractorjs and mocha how do I read all links on a site?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, mocha.js, protractor

I'm trying to read all HREF links on a site using protractor and mocha

I am not "married" to any of the technologies, but I'm under the impression that these are the current best in class technologies for driving selenium.

I'm working with the protractor Mocha example file that came with the project which I have tuned from the example code to read:

```
before(function() {
    driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000);
    ptor = protractor.wrapDriver(driver);
});

function Log(obj){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

it.only('should read all HREFS', function(done){
    ptor.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    var elements = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.tagName('a'));
    Log(protractor.By.tagName('a'));
    // {"using":"tag name","value":"a"}
    Log(elements);
    // Result: {}
    // Expected: a full list of every 'a' tag element on the angularjs homepage

});
```

What appears to be happening is the "elements" list is returning immediately as opposed to after the page loads.

How do I deal with that in selenium+protractor?

Answer (score 0):

OK - so turns out the Async was messing me up a little.

I've tuned the code to make this do what I've asked for above.

```
it.only('should read all HREFS', function(done){
    ptor.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    var elements = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.tagName('a'));
    Log(protractor.By.tagName('a'));
    Log(elements);  

    var a = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('a'));
    for (var element in a) {
        Log(element);
    }

// NOTE ***********************************
// this here is the "answer" the asynchonous nature of javascript means that I 
// do not have have access to the contents of the request until I am inside the "then"
// response
// 
// from there I have to use the same structure when executing the getAttribute method
    a.then(function(elements){

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            var link = elements[i];
            link.getAttribute('href')
                .then(function(value){
                    Log(value);
                });
        }

        for (e in elements){
            var link = elements[e];
            Log(link.getTagName());
        // I left this in my debugging code for the stackoverflow reader who might
        // want to know what other functions they can execute on the LINK object
            for (attribute in link) {
                Log(attribute);
                // "then"
                // "cancel"
                // "isPending"
                // "errback"
                // "driver_"
                // "id_"
                // "constructor"
                // "getDriver"
                // "toWireValue"
                // "schedule_"
                // "findElement"
                // "isElementPresent"
                // "findElements"
                // "click"
                // "sendKeys"
                // "getTagName"
                // "getCssValue"
                // "getAttribute"
                // "getText"
                // "getSize"
                // "getLocation"
                // "isEnabled"
                // "isSelected"
                // "submit"
                // "clear"
                // "isDisplayed"
                // "getOuterHtml"
                // "getInnerHtml"
                // "addCallback"
                // "addErrback"
                // "addBoth"
                // "addCallbacks"
            }
        };
    });
  });
```